# In Box Plot Chart, how can I set the average point to Diamond shape instead of standard Line shape

Tags: c#, charts

Does anyone know how can I set the box plot chart average point as a diamond shape instead of a normal line shape?

This is the output I want to achieve:

[image]

I researched online for a quite awhile and found some properties like point marker and marker style but still couldn't get the output I want...

**This is my latest code:**

```
    Chart Chart1= new Chart();
    Chart1.DataSource = dt;
    Chart1.Width = 800;
    Chart1.Height = 490;

    Chart1.Series.Add(new Series());
    Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;
    **Chart1.Series.Add(new Series());
    Chart1.Series[1].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;**

    List<object> List1 = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList<object>();

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {    
        Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(row["CUSTOMER"],
            new object[] { row["MIN"], row["MAX"], row["25TH_PERCENTILE"],
                           row["75TH_PERCENTILE"], row["AVG"], row["50TH_PERCENTILE"] });

        Chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(row["CUSTOMER"],
            new object[] { row["AVG"]});
    }

    Chart1.Series[0]["BoxPlotShowAverage"] = "false";

    //create chartareas
    ChartArea ca= new ChartArea();
    ca.AxisX = new Axis();
    ca.AxisY = new Axis();

    //databind
    Chart1.DataBind();
    Chart1.Visible = true;
```

This is the output I get:
[image]

**Issue Faced Now:** Same Average Value for Every Series in the Chart Even Though There is Different Average Value in Each Row of DataTable(dt).

Comment: replace `Chart1.Series[1].ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;` with `Chart1.Series[1].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point`

Comment: thanks @jstreet, it works! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [MSDN - Box Plot Chart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456709.aspx):

> **Chart Characteristics:** 
>   Supports markers: NO

One *hacky* way of doing it is to hide the "Avg" from the box plot chart by doing:

```
 Chart1.Series[0]["BoxPlotShowAverage"] = "false";
```

and then add a separate `Point` `Series` containing the average value:

```
 Chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(row["Customer"], new object[] { row["Avg"] });
```

and you'll get something similar to what you're looking for:

[image]

Comment: hi @jstreet, I have tried your solution but get a different output. I think i have did something wrongly but can't figure out what is it..Please look at my edited post. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note: `Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;` and `Chart1.Series[1].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;`

Comment: hi @jstreet, thanks for your help again! :) I can get the output but now I am trying to figure out why the average value is the same for each series on the chart even though there is different average value in each row of datatable(dt). I used the same foreach method for this point chart as what I have used to plot the box plot chart, but don't understand why only point chart will have same average value for every series on the chart, unlike the box plot chart. I have updated my post with the latest solution, please take a look, thanks a lot!

Comment: try populating both series inside one single `foreach` loop.

Comment: hi @jstreet, has tried to put both series inside one single foreach loop but still the same result.. please see my updated post thanks!

Comment: can you post the chart image you get?

Comment: Also, move `Chart1.Series[0]["BoxPlotShowAverage"] = "false";` before the `foreach` loop. That's how i have it....

Comment: hi @jstreet, has updated my post with the chart image I get. Ok has moved the chart statement before the foreach loop. I can produce the diamond shape but the average value is the same for each series on the chart even though there is different average value in each row of datatable(dt).

Comment: Perhaps you're misinterpreting your chart. One average is 10 and the other is 30, from your picture. And i see `star`s, not `diamond`s...

Comment: Actually that picture does not make a lot of sense.... your `XAxis` should show customer id or name, but it shows `Series1`, `Series2`...

Comment: Also, clean up your code a little: `List1` doesn't seem necessary in that context, and `Chart1.DataSource = dt;` is not necessary either....

Comment: hi @jstreet, thanks a lot for your help and guidance on this!! :) I appreciated your help! I managed to get the diamond shape to be plotted on the correct average point.